# Drop down selection - multiple

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have six drop downs which is not mandatory, sometimes there will be entry for 1 drop down, sometimes for 2 drop down so and so. I am getting the value to be selected in drop down from an excel file. 
Code to extract value from excel :-

```
WebElement lan1 =driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlLanguage1"));
Select lan1Sel = new Select(lan1);
lan1Sel.selectByVisibleText(data.getLanguage1().get(rowCnt));
```

I need to move to next option, after this drop down.How to do it? Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Need to move to the next drop down means what? You want to select same value in all the select_list?

Comment: After selecting the value  from the list you can move to the next field by using `element.click();`. Try if doing like this helps :
`WebElement license = driver.findElement(By.xpath("-- path to driving license textbox --"));
 license.click();`

Comment: Your question is not clear! After Selecting a value from the first Select Box what's the next operation you want to perform? Do you want to enter value into Driver License input box? if yes then just use sendkeys method from selenium . use : driver.findElement(By.xpath("-- path to driving license textbox --")).sendkeys("what you are trying to send to the input box")

Comment: @ReshmiAneesh : Can you add the html of the drop down and license section to your question?

Comment: @mbn217 I want to do the same, your reply solved my issue. thank you.